# rrbot_gazebo rrbot.launch - fails when topic laser scan read

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am able to launch the rrbot_gazebo rrbot.launch, and able to see the camera, but when I try to read the laser, just > rostopic echo /rrbot/laser/scan, gazebo dies with segfault.

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4131/rrbot_gazebo-rrbot.launch---fails-when-topic-laser-scan-read/) by [rguzman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/353/rguzman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rguzman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/353/rguzman/) on 2013-08-10**:
it works with the standard laser plugin, just changing "gpu_ray" x "ray" and "libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so" x "libgazebo_ros_laser.so"

**Comment by [viswa_1211](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8460/viswa_1211/) on 2019-03-04**:
@rguzman I tried the same with libgazeboroslaser.so. The simulation starts. When the ray hits an obstacle, the simulation stops with Segmentation Fault. Can you help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Answer in comments.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [onlytailei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3186/onlytailei/) on 2017-06-03**:
The same problem even without gpu on gazebo 8. Any suggestions?